# Numpy Error: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_

Tags: python, numpy

Not sure why I'm getting this error when I'm doing:

```
batched_outputs = []
batched_outputs.append(output_sliced)
batched_outputs = torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(batched_outputs))
```

Where `output_sliced` is a `numpy` array.

Comment: Assign `np.asarray(batched_outputs)` separately. It's good debugging practice

Comment: Please provide an MCVE if you need help. It's an MCVE if there are no unnecessary references to the rest of your project (which you did well), and I can paste it into my editor and run (which you didn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code seems to be working fine. Perhaps problem with your `output_sliced`?

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
batched_outputs = []
output_sliced = np.random.random((2,3))
batched_outputs.append(output_sliced)
batched_outputs = torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(batched_outputs))
```

I don't get any errors with the code above.

I don't know if you intended this, but do keep in mind that:

```py
batched_outputs = []
output_sliced = np.random.random((2,3))
batched_outputs.append(output_sliced)
print(np.asarray(batched_outputs).shape)
```

gives you

```
(1, 2, 3)
```