# Pytorch can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, classification

I am trying to create a PyTorch data-loader with variable image size. Here is a snippet of my code

```
def get_imgs(path_to_imgs):

    imgs = []
    for path in path_to_imgs:

        imgs.append(cv2.imread(path))

    imgs = np.asarray(imgs)    

    return imgs
```

The function above takes a list of paths and loads the images from the path to the list 'imgs'. BTW the images are not equal-sized. The list looks like imgs = [NumPy array, NumPy array ....]. However, when I convert the list to np.asarray it turns the list into dtype = object.

This is my dataloader class

```
class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

  def __init__(self, path_to_imgs, path_to_label):
        'Initialization'
        self.path_to_imgs = path_to_imgs
        self.path_to_label = path_to_label

        self.imgs = get_imgs(path_to_imgs)
        self.label = get_pts(path_to_label)

        self.imgs = torch.Tensor(self.imgs)             **Error here
        # self.imgs = torch.from_numpy(self.imgs)       ** I tried this as well. Same error

        self.label = torch.Tensor(self.label)

        self.len = len(self.imgs)

  def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the total number of samples'
        return self.len

  def __getitem__(self, index):

        return self.imgs, self.label
```

When I try to convert the list of images to tensor** it fails giving the following error

> can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.

I have looked similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55724123/typeerror-cant-convert-np-ndarray-of-type-numpy-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60849855/numpy-error-cant-convert-np-ndarray-of-type-numpy-object) but they were not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_imgs(path_to_imgs):

    imgs = []
    for path in path_to_imgs:
        imgs.append(torch.Tensor(cv2.imread(path)))

    return imgs
```

```
class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path_to_imgs, path_to_label):
        'Initialization'
        self.path_to_imgs = path_to_imgs
        self.path_to_label = path_to_label

        self.imgs = get_imgs(path_to_imgs)
        self.label = get_pts(path_to_label)

        # padding ops here (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#padding-layers)
        # for img in self.imgs:
        #     ...

        self.label = torch.Tensor(self.label)

        self.len = len(self.imgs)

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the total number of samples'
        return self.len

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        return self.imgs, self.label
```

Comment: so the unequal sizes are causing the issue? Can you please elaborate

Comment: @FarshidRayhan Neither in `numpy` nor in `torch` you can create one tensor from the list of tensors of different shapes. `numpy` creates an array of objects. But `torch` cannot convert objects to float tensors. Therefore, we save the images as tensors in the `get_imgs` function. And now, to create a tensor from the list of tensors, you need to pad them.